# vim-latexsuite syntax highlight in macro parameter

Tags: vim, vim-latex

I'm using vim with [vim-latex](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/)for editing my LaTeX-files. I notice that the `\begin{env}` and `\end{env}` doesn't colorize when they are in a macro parameter (the `\vary` command and `question` environment is part of [exsheets package](http://ctan.org/pkg/exsheets)):

```
\vary{
  \begin{question}
  \end{question}
}{
  \begin{question}
  \end{question}
}
```

I've attached a sample picture:
[image: explanation of my problem]

What should I do to vim colorize the `\begin{question}` inside `\vary`?

Comment: [vim-latexsuite doesn't change your syntax highlighting](https://sourceforge.net/p/vim-latex/mailman/message/29492276/), so this would be a question directly about the vim syntax file you have for TeX files.

Comment: I thought vim-latexsuite provides a syntax file. Do you've any idea how can I solve it?

Comment: On my vim setup (vim 7.4 on Ubuntu, default syntax highlighting), I don't get the error you have; have you added different syntax highlighting? Or perhaps you used a version of vim-latexsuite that provided a syntax file, which would be strange to discover.

Comment: I renamed `~/.vim` (so `vim` doesn't use any user-based file) but same behavior.

Comment: Ah, I think I see. My syntax highlighting doesn't distinguish the cases you were looking at (since I'm using terminal vim, not gvim), so it "looked right" to me. I'm sorry I led you astray. In any case, it's useful to know that it's an issue for default vim too, I think.